# Rail 3.2.2/Devise: deprecation warning with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I recently upgraded an app to rails 3.2.2.

I'm using Factory_girl

> Factory.sequence :name do |n|   "name-#{n}" end
>
> Factory.define :user do |u|   u.first_name{ Factory.next(:name) }
>   u.last_name   { |u| 'last_' + u.first_name }   u.password 'secret'
>   u.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }   u.sequence(:email) { |i|
>   "user_#{i}@example.com" }
>
> end

and this simple test

> specify {  Factory.build(:user).should be_valid }

generate the following warning

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `user_id'.
>   Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use`
>   attr_writer` etc. (called from block (2 levels) in 
>   at...

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 19):

It's probably because you haven't prepared/migrated your test database with updated column definitions, thus it thinks you're trying to arbitrarily set the attribute.

Run `rake db:test:prepare` to make sure it's updated.

[Here's the source code](http://rails.documentation.codyrobbins.com/3.2.2.rc1/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html) of that method, where you can see Rails checks for the column or attribute first, then warns if they're not found.

Comment: unfortunately it is not the issue. my test db is up to date. I've run the prepare task and I still have the same warning

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Sometimes I have to run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` to actually migrate it. Just an idea, check the actual test db to ensure the columns are present.

Answer (score 4):

I've met the same warning with the following code:

Ad model:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :ad do
        association :user
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :user do
        first_name {Factory.next(:first_name)}
        last_name {Factory.next(:last_name)}
        email {|x| "#{x.first_name}.#{x.last_name}#{Factory.next(:count)}@test.com"}
        password Forgery(:basic).password
        confirmed_at Date.today << 10
    end
end
```

Test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Ad do
    before(:each) do
        @ad = Factory.build(:ad)
    end

    "it is not valid without a user"
end
```

Running the test gave me a similar error.

Adding

```
attr_accessor :user
```

to the Ad model fixed the warning.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked for me without Devise. Thanks, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same warning while doing tests in Rspec and my issue was that I had a Parent model and Child model where I accidentally had this:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

......

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
end
```