# Deprecation warning on mass assignment of belongs to association on rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've recently updated an app from Rails 3.0.10 to Rails 3.2.8 and we started getting this Deprecation Warnings on our specs:

DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `profissional'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use`attr_writer` etc. (called from block (3 levels) in  at .../spec/models/agendamento/agendamento_spec.rb:109)

The line in question is: `Agendamento::Agenda.new(descricao: 'Agenda', profissional: profissional, situacao: :ativa)`. And Agenda has a belongs_to association with profissional.

Both databases are up-to-date with the last migration, so the answer to the other similar questions don't solve mine.

Is this really going to be deprecated and is not expected to work on future versions of Rails or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe you need to add:

    attr_accessor :professional

or

    attr_writer :professional

to your Agenda model.  That will remove the deprecation warning.

Comment: I thought so too.  Here's a similar question which may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544368/rail-3-2-2-devise-deprecation-warning-with-rspec

Comment: I am having a similar problem again on a polymorphic association, and the attr_accessor does not seem to solve that one =/  Still have to figure it out.  Did adding that solve your problem by the way?